# Catch and report bad json response from server with Retrofit + Moshi + Kotlin

Tags: android, retrofit, crashlytics, moshi

Once in a while, I see `Fatal Exception: x.y Required value 'firstName' (JSON name 'first_name') missing at $[1]` crash report in Crashlytics. Missing properties vary from report to report. I can not reprod these crashes so I need to put logging (that makes a network call to server / fire an firebase event with the broken/problematic json text) so I can examine it.

I tried following options but they wont work for me:

1. Make `firstName` nullable. This will ideally solve the issue but these reports are for various properties of various models. Making all variables nullable just kills the kotlin fun. Also Server is committed to send **firstName** so if I can show a json without one, they should fix it.
2. Add an interceptor to log **ALL request responses** and then check last network call before crash. But this will load app and backend with unnecessary logs which can quickly get bulky and messy.

I am not hoping to handle the error and avoid the crash (that would be great if there was a silver bullet).

Comment: Yeah, crashing the app because the server responded badly (be it a 5xx http error or missing data in the response body) is probably not what you want to do. Logging the issue and displaying an error view is probably better. What exactly is the question?

Comment: if you are using Retrofit, you can log these errors really easily, btw. fwiw, i made a tiny CallAdapter.Factory library for this exact use case: https://github.com/NightlyNexus/logging-retrofit

Comment: @EricCochran That's helpful but I can see that the onFaiure() only gives back call and throwable. It does not contain responseBody (which contains bad / unexpected json that I need to log).

Comment: correct. The HTTP response code and the response body are in onResponse. Just check for Response.isSuccess. Retrofit calls onResponse when there is any HTTP response.